# Как включить автоматический перенос слов по слогам?

Tags: html, css, ios, swift

У меня есть файлы html и css, чтобы показать мою книгу в моем приложении. И этот код:

```
let headerString = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.1\" />"
do {
            guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(readBookNumber)", ofType: "html")
                else {
                    print ("File reading error")
                    return
                }
            var content =  try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
            let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            
            content.changeHtmlStyle(font: "Iowan-Old-Style", fontSize:  UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "textSize"), fontColor: textColor)
            webView.loadHTMLString(headerString+content, baseURL: baseUrl)
        }
        catch {
            print ("File HTML error")
        }
```

Как включить автоматический перенос слов по слогам?

Что у меня есть:

> In June 2010 at
> the World Wide
> Developers Conference
> Apple
> announced version
> 4 of Xcode
> during the Developer
> Tools State
> of the Union address.

Что я хочу:

> In June 2010 at
> the World Wide
> Developers Con-
> ference, Apple
> announced ver-
> sion 4 of Xcode
> during the Devel-
> oper Tools State
> of the Union ad-
> dress.

Comment: css вроде как позволяет переносить только слова целиком, разделять на слога он не умеет (`word-wrap`, `word-break`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью css + html можно сделать перенос

- `word-wrap: break-word;` **по словам** + знаку переноса (`-`)
- `word-break: break-all;` жесткий перенос **по буквам**

```css
div {
  width: 150px; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

div.a {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

div.b {
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<h2>По словамp: break-word:</h2>
<div class="a"> This div contains a very-very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</div>

<h2>По буквам: break-all:</h2>
<div class="b"> This div contains a very-very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</div>
```

Для остального понадобиться **js**

**UPD**
[Переносы слов](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/perenosy-slov)

`&shy;` - выполняет ту же роль, что и тег `<wbr>` — не виден в обычном тексте и переносит слово на другую строку, при этом добавляя дефис

[hyphens](http://htmlbook.ru/css/hyphens) - сообщает браузеру, как расставлять переносы слов в блоке текста. Словарь переносов хранится в браузере и подключается только при наличии атрибута lang с кодом языка.

> На данный момент действительны следующие значения:
>
> - Android / Mac: manual | none | auto
> - Другие платформы: manual | none

[Источник](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/ed7e106e0e48b3afb160a5bdbb37649e307d2b05)

Comment: Ну это не совсем то, что мне нужно. По слогам слова не переносятся. Я не разбираюсь в css и html, но нашел этот код 
    `hyphens:auto;
     text-align:justify;
    -webkit-hyphens:auto;
    -webkit-hyphenate-character:"\2010";
    -webkit-hyphenate-limit-after:1;
    -webkit-hyphenate-limit-before:3;
    -moz-hyphens:auto;` Он по слогам практически правильно все разделяет, но иногда между но не всегда. Иногда большие пробелы оставляет между словами, хотя там можно бы разделить по слогам. Что в нем не так?

Comment: @User, у меня на винде `hyphens` не отображается, не с оперы не с хрома, но большие пробелы у вас скорее всего из-за `text-align:justify`